# My every word or Every my word

Tags: word-order, determiners

Which is correct:

> 1) My every word
>
> 2) Every my word ?

Answer (score 1):

In current English, *every* cannot be followed by another determiner, so *every my word* is not grammatical. It was grammatical in Early Modern English, so you will find it in Shakespeare.

*My every word* is fine, though I don't think many people would use it in everyday speech, apart from the idiom "hanging on my every word" (more usually used in the third person "hanging on his/her/their every word").

Comment: does it mean the same thing?

Comment: I suppose it does. But as I say, the first is not grammatical in current English.

Comment: just interested if the meaning had changed, as some things that sound like they should mean the same thing don't but can't remember any examples now.