# "every your thought" or "every thought of yours" or "every one of your thoughts"?

Tags: possessives, predeterminers

I always felt that ***every your thought*** sounded a bit awkward, but because it seemed to me formal and somewhat literary, I used it more in written texts. Here is one instance of it:

> A century and a half later, the *Northumberland Household Book* prescribes: "Whensoever any of his Lordeship Servauntes be comaunded to ride on message in Winter...that every of theym be allowed for the tyme for his being furth in his jomay... for every meall and for ***every his baiting***; and for his Hors every day and night of his saide jornay, ..." (*[Medieval Panorama](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Medieval_Panorama/-aRYk3mRD3wC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22every%20his%22&pg=PA324&printsec=frontcover)*, G. G. Coulton · 2010)

Is this use outdated?

Here is one more:

> With every hit he could feel anger leave his body and maturity take its place. With ***every his anger*** and pain faded, like a ghost. (*[Eyes of Fire](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=uYYZAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA52&dq=%22every%20his%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjmtqCMtMnyAhXHTMAKHbV3BJs4FBDoATAJegQICRAC)*, D H Rezek · 2011)

Is my intuition correct? Is it true that

> ***Every your*** thought is important to me.

is more formal than

> ***Every*** thought ***of yours*** is important to me?

"Every one of your thoughts" seems to slightly change the emphasis on the plural, so I am not sure I can use these three interchangeably. Note that I am interested particularly in the combination of "every" modifying nouns accompanied by their possessive pronouns.

Comment: I would regard 'every your thought' as not just awkward, but definitely an error. Where have you seen it? Quote and source please. 'Your every thought', though, is fine.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey It may be outdated use. Thanks for pointing out this is not acceptable English anymore, I had no idea...

Comment: Your quote gives the date as 1480 approx. I see that @ColinFine [said in April 2019](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/205815/my-every-word-or-every-my-word) "In current English, every cannot be followed by another determiner, so every my word is not grammatical. It was grammatical in Early Modern English, so you will find it in Shakespeare." but, unfortunately, he did not give any examples, and I have not been able to find any.

Comment: It looks though that some still use it today. Anyway, it's clearly safer to avoid it.

Comment: I had never heard of "DH Rezek", whose novel you found on Google Books. It does not look like great literature.

Comment: Mainly survives in the idiom "hanging on my/his/her/their every word"

Comment: If I was not aware that this is outdated use, is that a reason to downvote and close the question? I would have been happy with a negative answer too. @MichaelHarvey All your comments would make enough for one anwer...

Comment: This looks like a typo **“…with every [strike/blow?] his pain and anger faded”**. And there's definitely one too many "e"s in "with *eevery* hit" :)

Comment: @Mari-LouA Corrected the "eveery". Yes "with every strike" would make more sense. I found "every + possessive + noun" in old books I cannot find links to, and I had no idea it is considered ungrammatical today. So I am glad to make the discovery... I was corrected for this use by another non-native, and I was sure I had encountered it in books written in good English. Now I understand we were both right.

Comment: I found only four instances with "every your thought" and three were quoting the same passage (“**Allah knows every your thought**, every your desire! And He fills them with Power only if His desire is one with yours.” ) while the third was semi-literate, it seemed written by a non-native. I think the phrase is too rarefied a question for ELL.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22every+your+thought%22&tbm=bks&sxsrf=ALeKk03obsAFZKZNIBR8fYffYkIGiWfcqA:1629802699199&ei=y9AkYejDC8SXlwTi37qABw&start=0&sa=N&ved=2ahUKEwio1cGXwMnyAhXEy4UKHeKvDnA4FBDy0wN6BAgBEDs&biw=1106&bih=563&dpr=1.25 There are a few false positives among the results, so don't raise your hopes too high.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I am not interested to prove myself right! I just want to know what is correct. But this is clearly too old a use to be even recorded in the internet era. Yes, I understand now that this question is not for ELL. When I typed the question, I was really not aware that it was so complicated. I am thinking of addressing the issue on EL&U in a different form, but I doubt there is any material on the matter...

Comment: The usage in *Northumberland* is clearly old-fashioned. The Rezek quote is a parallel construction referring back to ***With** every [noun]* in the preceding sentence so it is not relevant here (and it sounds both awkward and incorrect to me anyway). I agree with @Michael that "every your thought" is an error in modern English.

Comment: @randomhead Now I do too!